# Prevent external acces to .php

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess, external

Is there a way to block external acces to a .php file (like in the URL) and allow if the .php file got called by jquery post?

Thanks!
Wouter0100

Comment: "jquery post" === external access. It's hard to separate those two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume because you say `like in the URL` you want to prevent `GET` requests.

You can put this at the top of your script to prevent people accessing it through the URL. You will then only be able to `POST` to it, such as jQuery POST.

```
<?PHP
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']!="POST")
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    exit;
?>
```

Be aware, other sources can still `POST` to the form as well. This method only prevents access through other methods such as `GET` requests. I.e. typing in the URL in the address bar.

Comment: You could send `header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');` instead of just exiting.

Comment: @RobinWinslow that's true. I was going for simplistic. But I will update with your suggestion, as it is useful :)

Comment: This works! Thanks! (And, i'm using my own 'error' handler for this, so no exit or header needed.)

Comment: Notice that this is still perfectly open "external access". A "jquery post" request is not the only thing that can set the request method to "POST".

Answer (score 1):

As it has been mentioned to you that allowing a `.php` to be accessed using jquery post is equivalent of providing an external access. The only way (and that is not very reliable) you can allow a php file to be accessed by jquery post is to check for `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` variable in your PHP code to be same as the URL that has sent jquery post.

Answer (score 1):

The easier way to do this would be to send a header with jquery that you later read with PHP. It's in no way a true protection, but it does prevent the users from sending requests without first inspecting the headers it's supposed to send.

For instance, in your jquery call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    },
    success: function(data) {
    }
});
```

And in your PHP:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] != 'XMLHttpRequest') {
    header("HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed");
    exit();
}
```